# Generic re-usable gridview with sorting,paging, filtering for asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have been given a task  of creating a common Gridview component which has following features:

1. Paging
2. sorting
3. Filtering

The objective is to reuse the component in almost all the web pages (.aspx), so that the look and feel, layout and behaviour remains uniform across the web site.

The grid has to be lightweight, preferably ajax based. I had several thoughts in mind:

1. extend the current asp.net Gridview  component.
2. Implement a very  own custom solution with ajax method pulling data, rendering happens on client side using some jquery templates..etc.

I am not sure where to start with. The requirements i have been give just says that create a common Grid component so that all others in my team can re-use the same component .

Please give me insight into which way I should approach the implementation so that in future this component is scalable as well as in the near future its re-usable across the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel, there are tons of opensource and pay grids out there to do what you wnat - Check out this grid (with complete source).  One of the nice features is that you can add a toolbar which you could use for your filtering.

http://jqmvcgrid.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery plugin [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) is very light weight and has all the features you need. You could use that.